# set data to unmapped data from loop

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I have tried below code where i am trying to get values by comparing key if it matches am setting the value to it. if it's not matching i need to map to different specific value in the same forloop while iterating

```
import json


data = {"time": "2018-09-29T16:45:00+0000","test":"gfds","ert":"erty"}
#data1 = json.loads(json_data) # json_data is a placeholder for your json
keys = ['results_count', 'test', 'utc_start_at', 'non_resource_bookable_capacity']

    
def find_key_value_pairs(q, keys, dicts=None):
    if not dicts:
        dicts = [q]
        q = [q]  

    data = q.pop(0)
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        data = data.values()

    for d in data:
        dtype = type(d)
        if dtype is dict or dtype is list:
            q.append(d)
            if dtype is dict:
                dicts.append(d)

    if q:
        return find_key_value_pairs(q, keys, dicts)

    return [(k, v) for d in dicts for k, v in d.items() if k in keys]
results = find_key_value_pairs(data, keys)
json_Obj={}
for k, v in results:
    json_Obj.update({k:v})

print(json_Obj)
```

Whatever unmatched keys are there, i need to match to some specific data. For ex: 'non_resource_bookable_capacity' is not available in data but whenever it check for 'non_resource_bookable_capacity' it should map to 'ert' same way 'time' is not available in data but it should map to 'utc_start_at' only. but not randomly. am stuck in this how to set to specific key value.

expected o/p:

```
{'utc_start_at': '2018-09-29T16:45:00+0000', 'non_resource_bookable_capacity': 'erty',
'test': 'gfds'
}
```

Can anyone guide me how can i achieve this?

Comment: Hi, please add piece of codes which is related to your question, not the whole program. Also add input and expected output. Good luck

Comment: @Hamed_gibago added expected o/p. I/p is already available in code .. data and keys

Answer (score 0):

Try this-- I added a second value to a list to imitate looping through a larger json file

```
data = [{"time": "2018-09-29T16:45:00+0000","test":"gfds","ert":"erty"}, {"time": "2020-09-29T16:45:00+0000","test":"abcd","ert":"wxyz"}]

for i in data:
    i['utc_start_at'] = i['time']
    i['non_resource_bookable_capacity'] = i['ert']
    
    del i['time'], i['ert']

print(data)
```

**Output:** [{'test': 'gfds', 'utc_start_at': '2018-09-29T16:45:00+0000', 'non_resource_bookable_capacity': 'erty'}, {'test': 'abcd', 'utc_start_at': '2020-09-29T16:45:00+0000', 'non_resource_bookable_capacity': 'wxyz'}]